# Django website 400 error from a client on Mac, Chrome/Firefox

Tags: django, macos, google-chrome, firefox, nginx

I am developing with Django,Nginx, Gunicorn on a mac with chrome. I have heard that a tester in my company has been receiving 400 errors in both firefox and Chrome, but not with Safari. I am aware of that a 400 error is a bad request error and is a user derived error. He has stated that there were also the same error on different devices and machines, using the same browsers.

I have not been able to reproduce this error myself and have not found a device that could not access the website.

Could this be a compatibility issue? He has cleared the cashe and cookies but I am not sure for how for back he has done so.

What scenarios could this be a developer derived issue?

Comment: Have you set https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts ? I usually get that error because of that issue

Comment: Have you checked your logs? Let the person visit the site again and check your traceback to see if there's an error.

Comment: My allowed hosts are set. @onyeka how could I check my logs on the server?

Comment: Well, I don't know honestly, it depends on your server setyp. Did you set up logging for your django installation? You could also check your wherever your nginx error logs are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was how I put in the domain names into allowed_hosts:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'website.org',
    'website_2.org',
    ]
```

should have been

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.website.org',
    '.website.org',
    ]
```

the '.' allowed the 'www' prefix to be used. Previously it was failing for those who typed www before the website address.